# How to use other class using sql connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image: My image]

I have created "Commondata" class, a connection string. How to use on this from class

```
public partial class MainCastApply : Form
{
    public MainCastApply()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Commondata.conString.connectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [SURNAME]FROM [ELE_TRY].[dbo].[E_DETAIL]order by SURNAME ", con);
        DataTable dtdb = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtdb);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dtdb;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Commondata.conString.connectionString`? Normally you would just store the connectionstring in a .config file and call it using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString`

Answer (score 0):

replace initial catlog from connectin string with Initial Catalog.
 your connectin string must be public static